# Accessing values in a list of JObjects

Tags: c#, json

I have a JObject that is returning values in a similar format to below,

```
{
    "0": {
        "OPTION_LIST_ID": 1,
        "NAME": "listname",

    },
    "1": [
        {
            "OPTION_ID": 1,
            "OPTION_LIST_ID": 1,
            "KEY_VALUE": "value1",
            "LABEL": "label1"
        },
        {
            "OPTION_ID": 2,
            "OPTION_LIST_ID": 1,
            "KEY_VALUE": "value2",
            "LABEL": "label2"
        }
    ]
```

I want to be able to loop through this list and return the last value in the list, and then access the KEY_VALUE from the last option entered, and I am really struggling with how to achieve this.

```
   foreach (JObject content in jArray.Children<JObject>())
   {
    ...
   }
```

I have this code that returns the above but really don't know how to go about trying to get the last option in the list.

Comment: when you format the object properly, it's easy to see the `0` entry and the `1` entry are a different format. `0` is one object, `1` is an array.

Comment: Try this: jArray.Children<JArray>().Last()
and add this in the top of the C# file using System.Linq;

Comment: When you say "loop through the list", what do you mean? For `0` you have an object as value, and for `1` an array. How do you know where to look?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way doing this (without looping through the array) with JSON.net might be directly accessing your object:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJson);
var value2 = result["1"][1].KEY_VALUE; // property "1" -> object in array at index 1
// output: value2
```

But if you really want to loop through I'd do it this way:

```
foreach (JToken property in result)
{
    var arrays = property.Children<JArray>();
    foreach (var array in arrays)
    {
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            var val = item.Value<string>("KEY_VALUE");
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}
// output: value1, value2
```